# Simple solution for golang tour webcrawler exercise

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I'm new to Go and I saw some solutions for this exercise, but I think they are complex...

In my solution everything seems simple, but I've got a deadlock error. I can't figure out how to properly close channels and stop loop inside main block. Is there a simple way to do this?

[Solution on Golang playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qKgBdqlmIB)

Thanks for any/all help one may provide!

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

type SafeCache struct {
    cache map[string]bool
    mux   sync.Mutex
}

func (c *SafeCache) Set(s string) {
    c.mux.Lock()
    c.cache[s] = true
    c.mux.Unlock()
}

func (c *SafeCache) Get(s string) bool {
    c.mux.Lock()
    defer c.mux.Unlock()
    return c.cache[s]
}

var (
    sc = SafeCache{cache: make(map[string]bool)}
    errs, ress = make(chan error), make(chan string)
)

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    var (
        body string
        err error
        urls []string
    )

    if ok := sc.Get(url); !ok {
        sc.Set(url)
        body, urls, err = fetcher.Fetch(url)
    } else {
        err = fmt.Errorf("Already fetched: %s", url)
    }

    if err != nil {
        errs <- err
        return
    }

    ress <- fmt.Sprintf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    go Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
    for {
        select {
        case res, ok := <-ress:
            fmt.Println(res)
            if !ok {
                break
            }
        case err, ok := <-errs:
            fmt.Println(err)
            if !ok {
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "http://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
            "http://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/cmd/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: maybe I somehow need to extract usefull information from `fakeFetcher` like that there is no more urls to fetch and I need to close channels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can solve this with [sync.WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup)

1. You can start listening your channels in separate goroutines.
2. `WaitGroup` will coordinate how many goroutines do you have.

`wg.Add(1)` says that we're going to start new goroutine.

`wg.Done()` says that goroutine is finished.

`wg.Wait()` blocks goroutine, until all started goroutines aren't finished yet.

This 3 methods allows you to coordinate goroutines.

[Go playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/HnFG366v-C)

PS. you might be interested in [sync.RWMutex](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex) for your `SafeCache`

Comment: Thank you so much! Very elegant solution!